# Regex full name sepreted by comma

Tags: regex

I want to create Regex to any numbers fullname separeted by comma if only one fullname comma not needed

John Smith;Tom Anderson;Bill Douglas;......

```
^.*(;){0,}
```

Now it's my regex but allows more than one time using comma
Adam Smith;;;;;Bill Douglas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this: `^[^;\n]+(?:;[^;\n]+)*$`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DIh5rr/1/)**

**Explained:**

```
^               # Begin of line
      [^;\n]+   # Non-';/newline' character repeated 1 or more times
  (?:;[^;\n]+)* # ( ';' + names ) repeated 0 or more times
$               # End of line
```